# Using WMS layer transparency with Geoserver, Openlayers and Drupal?

Tags: geoserver, style, openlayers-2, transparency-opacity, drupal

I am using OpenLayers in Drupal to display Geoserver WMS data. I can get the layer to overly properly, however the raster layer (png) has a white background I cannot remove. I have created a style in Geoserver using:
         ...
         FeatureTypeStyle - Rule - RasterSymbolizer - ColorMap - ColorMapEntry

However, even though this style is referenced in the 'Styles' for the OpenLayers layer in Drupal, nothing I do to this style file makes any changes to the map. ie: the background is always white. I have also tried to use opacity to make the entire layer transparent, but nothing changes. Drupal does not seem to be applying the style to the layer.

I am not sure if it matters, but the Geoserver information is provided by an external WMS server: http://nowcoast.noaa.gov/wms/com.esri.wms.Esrimap/obs?service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities

Has anybody had this problem and found the proper fix?

Comment: I had a similar problem but mine is not raster but polygon. The image should look something like this: ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LreuK.png) but it looks like this on GeoServer: ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XuQJq.png) But when i change the S3_B0_I1e_ column in attribute table from 0 to 1, it works fine. Did you solve the problem yet?

Comment: You say you are using GeoServer but your link is to an ESRI ArcIMS WMS service (not GeoServer).